# Get ID from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

A forum has this 5 tables (many more but this 5 are important for the query):

- posts
- topics
- topic_watch
- bookmarks
- topics_ignore

I am **trying to get the topic_id (grouped)** where the user has **posted in, has watched or has bookmarked a topic** and take care of the ignored topics. In short:

I  want a list of the IDs ordered by time, not caring which table they come from.

I build this SQL QUERY:

```
SELECT t.topic_id
  FROM posts p 
  LEFT 
  JOIN topics t 
    ON p.topic_id = t.topic_id
  LEFT 
  JOIN topics_watch w 
    ON w.user_id = p.poster_id 
   AND w.topic_id = t.topic_id
  LEFT 
  JOIN bookmarks b 
    ON b.user_id = p.poster_id 
   AND b.topic_id = t.topic_id
  LEFT 
  JOIN topics_ignore i 
    ON i.user_id = p.poster_id 
   AND i.topic_id = t.topic_id
 WHERE p.poster_id = 109606 
   AND i.topic_id IS NULL 
   AND t.topic_last_post_time > 1610274162 
 GROUP 
    BY t.topic_id 
 ORDER 
    BY t.topic_last_post_time DESC
```

**Problem:**

The query is working but **does not take care** of the **topics_watch and bookmarks table**. That means, if the user has watched or bookmarked a topic, the topic_id is not coming up in the list. The ignoring works.

More Informations:

The topics table contains all infos about the topic. The bookmark and the topic_watch table has only two columns. user_id, topic_id. I am trying to get a list of all topic_ids where the user has posted in (posts), has a entry of topic_watch or bookmark.

Any Ideas what I am doing wrong? Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: And, out of curiousity, why isn't it `b.user_id = p.poster_id`?

Comment: Because the user is in the posts table the poster_id and in the bookmarks table the user is the user_id. The bookmarks table has only 2 columns. user_id, topic_id

Comment: That doesn't answer my question !?!?!

Comment: I appreciate your help very much but I dont know exaclty how I can describe it more. I does not use b.user_id = p.poster_id because the main table is the topics table.

Comment: I have changed it to b.user_id = p.poster_id and w.user_id = p.poster_id but the result is the same. The list doest not have the topic_ids from bookmarks and topic_watch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not aggregation function so yo don't need  group

if you nedd  distinct result add dictinct clause

```
SELECT DICTINCT t.topic_id, w.topic_id, b.topic_id
FROM posts p 
LEFT JOIN topics t ON p.topic_id = t.topic_id
LEFT JOIN topics_watch w ON w.user_id = 109606 AND w.topic_id = t.topic_id
LEFT JOIN bookmarks b ON b.user_id = 109606 AND b.topic_id = t.topic_id
LEFT JOIN topics_ignore i ON i.user_id = 109606 AND i.topic_id = t.topic_id 
WHERE p.poster_id = 109606 
   AND i.topic_id IS NULL 
    AND t.topic_last_post_time > 1610274162 
ORDER BY t.topic_last_post_time DESC
```

the use of group by without aggregation function  in version < 5.7 return unpredicatble result and for version > 5.7 produce and error

But If you need  a result with rows merged between the table you could use UNION

```
    SELECT t.topic_id, t.topic_last_post_time 
    FROM posts p 
    INNER JOIN topics t ON p.topic_id = t.topic_id
    LEFT JOIN topics_ignore i ON i.user_id = 109606 AND i.topic_id = t.topic_id 
    WHERE p.poster_id = 109606 
           AND i.topic_id IS NULL 
            AND t.topic_last_post_time > 1610274162 
      

    UNION 
    SELECT w.topic_id, NULL
    FROM topics_watch w 
    WHERE  w.user_id = 109606 

    UNION 
    SELECT b.topic_id, NULL
    FROM bookmarks b 
    WHERE  b.user_id = 109606 

    ORDER BY topic_last_post_time DESC
```

Comment: Thank you very much for getting into. What I see is, you removed the group (thank you) and added DISTINCT (you missed a S). I changed my QUERY but the topic_id from bookmarks and watch is still missing. Any Ideas? Thank you

Comment: update your question and add  a proper data sample and the expected  result  ..anyway . have update the answer  adding explitally the column you are looking for  ..  if you see the result the could be you are looking for UNION instead  of left join

Comment: Thank you. If I add w.topic_id, b.topic_id, the query is empty. The expected result is the topic_id from bookmarks and watch.

Comment: I updated my first post. Maybe its more clear?!

Comment: I  want a list of the IDs ordered by time, not caring which table they come from.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I have tested everything. Your first provided query does not list the topic_ids from bookmark and watch. The second query is working but there is only 1 little problem. When I run this query its says, wrong usage of ORDER BY and Union. That means the first "order by" is wrong I guess. If I keep only the last one its saysing Unknown column 'topic_last_post_time' in 'order clause' . If I add topic_last_post_time to the first select with topic_last_post_time its saying SELECT statements have a different number of columns. Any I ideas how to sort this?

Comment: Thank you very much for help. Its much appreciate it. I have tested your solution. but now comes the error I said before: "The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns". This means, if you use UNION all combined SELECTs need the same selection. That means in my humble opinion, I have to add t.topic_last_post_time  also to the other Selections, but then I need a left join to the phpbb_topics too. I think this is to much?!

Comment: as in my sample  you must have the same number of column in all the select merged  by UNION  .if you have not some column  you must add  a NULL column in correspondant position  ..  r .. Anyway i.m not in your db  ..  could some columns must be retrived  by join and in this case you can use the  joined  resutl  ..depend from your tables design   ... hope is clea

Comment: wow, now its working like a charm. That NULL to bookmark and watch was the solution. thank you thousend times. If you provide me a paypal adress I could send you something.

Comment: @LarsVegas   . very kind of you .. but everything I do on stackoverflow .. is only and exclusively free for everyone .. if in the future you need professional advice then we can get in touch and evaluate what you may need .. however yours comment really made me very happy

Comment: you are most welcome. Ok, I understand. I need often professional advice. if you provide me an email or a website (via chat or private message?!) where I can contact you it would be great for upcoming projects, advice etc. I would be happy to have such a talented developer on my contact list.

Comment: @LarsVegas  . i have temporarly added one my email address to my profile if you use this you ca send me your concat so we can continue in private ..  many thanks

Comment: Thank you. I have wrote you an email. You can remove the email from your profile.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to get a list of all topic_ids where the user has posted in (posts), has a entry of topic_watch or bookmark.

This sounds like `exists`:

```
SELECT t.topic_id
FROM posts p JOIN
     topics t 
     ON p.topic_id = t.topic_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM topics_ignore i 
                  WHERE i.user_id = p.poster_id AND
                        i.topic_id = t.topic_id
                 ) AND
      (EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM topics_watch w 
               WHERE w.user_id = p.poster_id AND
                     w.topic_id = t.topic_id
              ) OR      
       EXISTS (SELECT 1  
               FROM bookmarks b 
               WHERE b.user_id = p.poster_id AND
                     b.topic_id = t.topic_id
              )
     )
WHERE p.poster_id = 109606 AND
      t.topic_last_post_time > 1610274162 
GROUP BY t.topic_id
ORDER BY t.topic_last_post_time DESC;
```

Note that because of the `ORDER BY`, I'm keeping the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

As an aside, here's an example of valid use of a LEFT JOIN...

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.topic_id
  FROM posts p 
  LEFT 
  JOIN topics t 
    ON p.topic_id = t.topic_id
   AND t.topic_last_post_time > 1610274162 
  LEFT 
  JOIN topics_watch w 
    ON w.user_id = p.poster_id 
   AND w.topic_id = t.topic_id
  LEFT 
  JOIN bookmarks b 
    ON b.user_id = p.poster_id 
   AND b.topic_id = t.topic_id
  LEFT 
  JOIN topics_ignore i 
    ON i.user_id = p.poster_id 
   AND i.topic_id = t.topic_id
 WHERE p.poster_id = 109606 
   AND i.topic_id IS NULL 
 ORDER 
    BY t.topic_last_post_time DESC
```

...athough it's a little odd to only select from the LEFT JOINed table.

Comment: Thank you very much for getting into. The query gives not error but the topic_ids from topics_watch and bookmarks are missing in the list. Any Ideas?

Comment: As I say, this was just an example of a query with a LEFT JOIN. Elsewhere, I've explained what action you should consider taking in order to address your problem.